# Eclipse: debugging large C project without compiling in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

I have large C project which I'm compiling manually and then debugging via GDB.

I'm already editing source in Eclipse, but I am not able to compile it there, because of complex and multiple makefile.

Is it possible only to launch app via Eclipse for debugging as via GDB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just set up the debugger to point to the binary and have it launch it.  Just make sure you compile it with the right flags (-ggdb and -g3 for symbols).  If you have it imported as a Makefile project, it should be able to automatically map your code to the symbols.

Basic instructions are here: http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/debugging-with-eclipse.html